# Session taking its own sweet time to be Destroyed

Tags: php

I have created a user page with a menu that contains a **logout** button. Upon clicking the button, the user is directed to a logout page with the following code:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

include("/var/www/include/header.inc");
echo "<h>Logout Success</h>";
include("/var/www/include/menu.inc");
include("/var/www/include/footer.inc");
```

The code in the **menu.inc** file is written such that:

```
if(@$_SESSION['login'] == "yes")
{
 // show expanded menu
}
else
{
 // show normal menu
}
```

What I am seeing now after logging out is the **expanded menu**. It seems that the menu is being included faster than the session can be destroyed, thus creating an impression that the user is still logged in. Is there a way to avoid such a situation?

Comment: Make sure you check out the examples (and fine print) for [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) (remember there are cookies and other information that may need to be cleaned up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[session_destroy](https://www.php.net/session_destroy) doesn't unset the $_SESSION array, so the rest of the page after session_destroy will still see it. You could simply try this

```
session_destroy(); 
unset($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Thank you! `unset` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

> `session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. **It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session**, or unset the session cookie.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: Was just about to reference that.

Answer (score 0):

To completely clear all session data you have to use something similar to

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

This is explained in PHP manual:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables
>   again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.